# Class IDs and their relevant class names for YOLOv8 model

Tags: yolo, yolov8

What are the class IDs and their corresponding class names for YOLOv8 models? I understand there are approximately 80 classes in the object detection model of YOLOv8. However, I'm looking to specifically identify each class along with their respective class IDs. Additionally, do all YOLO models (yolov3, yolov5, yolov7, yolov8) have the same number of classes and corresponding class IDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what dataset was used to pre-train yolo model. It was a COCO dataset with a corresponding class list for Ultralitics yolov8 and yolov5 pre-trained models. Loading [different](https://docs.ultralytics.com/models/) yolo models using Ultralitics library, you can check this information by running this code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt') # yolov3-v7
model.names
```

```
{0: 'person',
 1: 'bicycle',
 2: 'car',
 3: 'motorcycle',
 4: 'airplane',
 5: 'bus',
 6: 'train',
 7: 'truck',
 8: 'boat',
 9: 'traffic light',
 10: 'fire hydrant',
 11: 'stop sign',
 12: 'parking meter',
 13: 'bench',
 14: 'bird',
 15: 'cat',
 16: 'dog',
 17: 'horse',
 18: 'sheep',
 19: 'cow',
 20: 'elephant',
 21: 'bear',
 22: 'zebra',
 23: 'giraffe',
 24: 'backpack',
 25: 'umbrella',
 26: 'handbag',
 27: 'tie',
 28: 'suitcase',
 29: 'frisbee',
 30: 'skis',
 31: 'snowboard',
 32: 'sports ball',
 33: 'kite',
 34: 'baseball bat',
 35: 'baseball glove',
 36: 'skateboard',
 37: 'surfboard',
 38: 'tennis racket',
 39: 'bottle',
 40: 'wine glass',
 41: 'cup',
 42: 'fork',
 43: 'knife',
 44: 'spoon',
 45: 'bowl',
 46: 'banana',
 47: 'apple',
 48: 'sandwich',
 49: 'orange',
 50: 'broccoli',
 51: 'carrot',
 52: 'hot dog',
 53: 'pizza',
 54: 'donut',
 55: 'cake',
 56: 'chair',
 57: 'couch',
 58: 'potted plant',
 59: 'bed',
 60: 'dining table',
 61: 'toilet',
 62: 'tv',
 63: 'laptop',
 64: 'mouse',
 65: 'remote',
 66: 'keyboard',
 67: 'cell phone',
 68: 'microwave',
 69: 'oven',
 70: 'toaster',
 71: 'sink',
 72: 'refrigerator',
 73: 'book',
 74: 'clock',
 75: 'vase',
 76: 'scissors',
 77: 'teddy bear',
 78: 'hair drier',
 79: 'toothbrush'}
```